# Why does add(Component) in a loop not work?

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code in a method:

```
public panel(){
    aHoles = new JTextField(2);
    aBears = new JTextField(2);
    aPenguins = new JTextField(2);
    aHolesLabel = new JLabel("Amount of holes:");

    String[] Vars = {"aHoles", "aBears", "aPenguins", "aHolesLabel"};

    for(int x = 0; x < Vars.length; x++){
        add(Vars[x]);
    }
}
```

I tried using a loop to add the components to the JPanel instead of manually using `add()` each time as it seemed more efficient, however, this is giving me the following error:

`The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments String`

I know that is because of the strings in the array, the problem is is that when I convert those strings to variables for example:

```
    String[] Vars = {aHoles, aBears, aPenguins, aHolesLabel};
```

It also gives me an error, because you can't have variables in an array.

Is there a possible workaround to this? Or should I just use `add(Component)` manually instead of in a loop?

Comment: java can´t identify variables as names from a `String`. if you´d want to do so you´d need to use reflection or a proper `Component[] arr`.

Comment: @Berger I am not only using JLabels, there are a bunch of other types as well.

Comment: If you just want to add all of your elments consider a Stream : `Stream.of(aHoles,aBears,aPenguins,aHolesLabel).forEach(c -> add(c));`

Comment: Hmm, from a design point of view (making variable names easier to understand) I'd use `numHoles` of `amountOfHoles` instead. Just using the prefix `a` might be misleading (I interpreted it as "array"). You might know the meaning of that now but probably will have difficulties when revisiting your code several months from now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It also gives me an error, because you can't have variables in an array.

No, it gives you an error because you cannot store `Component` objects in an array of `String`s. If you use an array of an appropriate type, you can have variables in its initializer:

```
aHoles = new JTextField(2);
aBears = new JTextField(2);
aPenguins = new JTextField(2);
aHolesLabel = new JLabel("Amount of holes:");
Component[] components = {aHoles, aBears, aPenguins, aHolesLabel};
```

It is important to declare `components` *after* you have initialized the fields.

Comment: as a sidenote, please write variable names, following the naming convention, in lowercase as `Component[] vars`.